# Where can I find some tutorials or just information about Riak mobile client (BucketDB)?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, erlang, riak

Ater watching this amazing presentation http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Riak-BucketDB-Mobile by Kresten Krab Thorup about using Riak in mobile i tried to find some information about Riak mobile client - BucketDB accross the internet or github but couldn't find anything.
Can someone clearify this for me? Where can I download BucketDB, read about it, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reaching out to [Trifork](http://www.trifork.com), who wrote the code. I don't believe it has been open sourced.

You could also ask Kresten himself on Twitter: [@drkrab](https://twitter.com/drkrab).